# How does bundling as a bundler in Ardor work?

Tags: nxt, proof-of-stake, ardor, bundler

What do the bundling options mean in Ardor when you are bundling?

- Minimum Rate
- Rate
- Fee Limit
- Overpay

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this post can help:

https://thewiring.com/2017/05/19/ardor-fees-child-chain-fees-bundlers-forgers-lets-clarify/

Hope it helps a bit

> The idea behind Ardor is brilliant. And sometimes brilliant ideas
>   require some time to be fully understood.
>
> One of the great features of Ardor is that there can be many child
>   chains running under the blockchain infrastructure built on the Ardor
>   nodes (main chain). At the release of the live Ardor software in Q3
>   2017, all the functionalities of the current NXT will be implemented
>   in the first Ardor child chain called Ignis.
>
> But one thing that is apparently not clear to everybody is how the
>   fees structure looks like in the child chains and in the Ardor main
>   chain. So let’s clarify.
>
> Let’s start from the Ardor main chain.
>
> Forging blocks on the Ardor main chain will work as today’s NXT
>   forging. The Proof of Stake protocol allows the forging node with more
>   tokens to have better chances to forge a block. Forging is the
>   equivalent of mining in the NXT/Ardor world. The reward of a forged
>   block is the sum of the transaction fees within that block.
>
> These blocks will contain transactions from the main chain and from
>   the child chains. The Ardor main chain will be the only one forging
>   and providing the blockchain infrastructure to all child chains.
>
> So that’s clear. Ardor’s forging process works as today’s NXT forging
>   with the exception that there are also transactions from the child
>   chains packed in the same blocks.
>
> Let’s now move to the child chains. Let’s take for example Ignis, the
>   first child chain of Ardor.
>
> Users doing transactions within Ignis do not have to worry about Ardor
>   fees. They can simply transfer Ignis from one account to the other,
>   issue an Asset, send a message, etc by just paying a fee in Ignis. The
>   child chain fees can change because they will be defined by the
>   “bundlers”.
>
> So what is a “bundler”? A “bundler” is the link between the child
>   chain and the main chain. It’s the one that collects the child chain
>   fees and then pays the main chain (Ardor) to pack those transactions
>   in a block.
>
> There will be bundlers for each child chain and anyone can setup a
>   bundler as long the account holds some Ardor.
>
> Here is how the Bundler setup page looks like (example for Ignis):
>
> The field “Minimum Rate” is a multiplier for the defined Ardor fee for
>   that specific transaction. The result of that multiplication will be
>   the minimum transaction fee in child chain token users will have to
>   pay so that the bundler will bundle their child chain transaction.
>
> “Fee Limit” is the total amount you want to spend in Ardor fees.
>
> “Overpay” is the extra you want to pay more in case of competing
>   bundlers. This is a multiplier of what you will pay in terms of Ardor
>   fee.
>
> Let’s hypothetically assume that these are the fixed prices for a
>   couple of transaction in Ardor (still in development so let’s not be
>   too picky with the exact amounts):
>
> Basic transaction (money transfer, sending message, etc): 0.1 Ardor
>   Asset issuing: 1000 Ardor Now lets assume a bundler is set with these
>   parameters:
>
> Minimum Rate: 10 Fee Limit: 200 Overpay: 0.1 Someone now sends a
>   message to someone else in the Ignis child chain. The client will
>   automatically set the fee to the minimum fee offered by the bundlers.
>   Let’s assume that our bundler is the only one, then the fee that will
>   be applied will be:
>
> 0.1 Ardor fee x 10 Minimum Rate = 1 Ignis
>
> So the message will be delivered with 1 Ignis fee.
>
> The bundler then has to pay 0.1 Ardor + (0.1 Ardor x 0.1 Overpay) =
>   0.11 Ardor
>
> Let’s set another bundler with these parameters:
>
> Minimum Rate: 1 Fee Limit: 5000 Overpay: 2 Someone issues an Asset on
>   the Ignis child chain. Here is how the fees will look like:
>
> 1000 Ardor fee x 1 Minimum Rate = 1000 Ignis
>
> So the Asset will cost 1000 Ignis to the user.
>
> The bundler instead will pay 1000 Ardor + (1000 Ardor x 2 Overpay) =
>   3000 Ardor
>
> As the bundler has set a Fee Limit of 5000, it can afford to pay the
>   3000 Ardor mentioned above and still have 2000 Ardor budget for the
>   following “bundles”.
>
> Keep in mind that the bundler gets the child chain fees, and this is
>   where it gets interesting. The bundlers will then have to follow the
>   exchange rate between, for example, Ardor and Ignis and define the
>   Bundler in a way that he/she can recover the expenses.
>
> Let’s assume that 1 Ardor = 1 Ignis in terms of value.
>
> Let’s suppose that we have a Bundler set in the following way:
>
> Minimum Rate: 1 Fee Limit: 1000 Overpay: 0 Someone sends a message and
>   pays a fee of 0.1 Ignis (0.1 fixed Ardor fee multiplied by Minimum
>   Rate 1) to the bundler.
>
> So the bundler received a value 0.1 Ignis and pays a 0.1 Ardor as the
>   value of Ardor and Ignis, in this example are the same, then there is
>   no loss and no gain for the Bundler.
>
> Assuming the same Bundler defined above, but the value of Ardor is 10
>   times the value of Ignis, so you need 10 Ignis to buy 1 Ardor.
>
> In that case there would be a loss for the Bundler as it will receive
>   0.1 Ignis fee but will pay 0.1 Ardor fee which is worth 10 times more. So in that scenario the Bundlers have to adjust their Bundler settings
>   to be more reasonable financially, in this case a 0 gain/loss would be
>   achieved by setting Minimum Rate to 10.
>
> This is where more Bundlers will have to compete to be the most
>   attractive but also to make a little gain maybe. This will be defined
>   by the market.
>
> I hope this example helps to understand the fee structure in Ardor,
>   but please be aware that Ardor is still being developed so things
>   might be different when it will go live.

Comment: Sites die, best to copy paste the content here.